# MongoDB import to different collections set by a field

Tags: mongodb, import, pymongo, mongoimport, database

I have a file called data.json and extracted with `mongoexport`, with the following structure:

```
{"id":"63","name":"rcontent","table":"modules"}
{"id":"81","name":"choicegroup","table":"modules"}
{"id":"681","course":"1242","name":"Requeriments del curs","timemodified":"1388667164","table":"page"}
{"id":"682","course":"1242","name":"Guia d'estudi","timemodified":"1374183513","table":"page"}
```

What I need is to import this file into my local `mongodb` with a command like `mongoimport` or with `pymongo`, but storing every line in the collection named after the table value.

For example, the collection *modules* would contain the documents

```
{"id":"63","name":"rcontent"} and {"id":"81","name":"choicegroup"}
```

I've tried with `mongoimport` but I haven't seen any option which allows that. Does anyone know if there is a command or a method to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic steps for this using python are:

1. parse the `data.json` file to create python objects
2. extract the `table` key value pair from each document object
3. insert the remaining doc into a pymongo collection

Thankfully, pymongo makes this pretty straightforward, as below:

```
import json

from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()  # this will use default port and host
db = client['test-db']  # select the db to use
with open("data.json", "r") as json_f:
    for str_doc in json_f.readlines():
        doc = json.loads(str_doc)
        table = doc.pop("table")  # remove the 'table' key 
        db[table].insert(doc)
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.

Comment: This code will work only if every document in the json file is written in a line on its own.
If the document is splitted into number of lines - it woudn't work.
You can parse it with ijson parser (that will parse it dynamically)